# sum a similar set of all colume in Python Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm a beginner in Python pandas
I have trouble collecting trades in this CV file, please help
How do I write the command to add the size of all similar currency pairs in Pandas
For example, the total size of all side=buy symbol=btc-irt

side-   symbol- size

buy-         btc-irt-    0.011

buy-         btc-irt-    0.0045

sell-    btc-irt-      0.0001

sell-    btc-irt-      0.0001

Comment: Do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

For summing column values in a csv file, you can use pandas to load and group the values.

Try this code:

```
import pandas as pd

s = '''
side- symbol- size
buy- btc-irt- 0.011
buy- btc-irt- 0.0045
sell- btc-irt- 0.0001
sell- btc-irt- 0.0001
buy- eth-irt- 0.022
buy- eth-irt- 0.0046
sell- eth-irt- 0.0011
sell- eth-irt- 0.0021
'''.strip()

with open("data.csv",'w') as f: f.write(s) # write test file


#### main script ####

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=' ') # load data, columns separated by space
print('---- dataframe ----\n',df)

gb = df.groupby(["side-","symbol-"]).sum() # group by two columns, sum of third column
print('\n\n---- grouped ----\n',gb)
```

Output

```
---- dataframe ----
    side-   symbol-    size
0   buy-  btc-irt-  0.0110
1   buy-  btc-irt-  0.0045
2  sell-  btc-irt-  0.0001
3  sell-  btc-irt-  0.0001
4   buy-  eth-irt-  0.0220
5   buy-  eth-irt-  0.0046
6  sell-  eth-irt-  0.0011
7  sell-  eth-irt-  0.0021


---- grouped ----
                   size
side- symbol-
buy-  btc-irt-  0.0155
      eth-irt-  0.0266
sell- btc-irt-  0.0002
      eth-irt-  0.0032
```

Comment: thanks for your guide
This gives an error message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubu/Desktop/cvs/b.py", line 8, in <module>
    gb = df.groupby(["side-","symbol-"]).sum() # group by two columns, sum of third column
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 7884, in groupby
    return groupby(

Comment: This is a continuation of the error message

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 2522, in groupby
    return klass(obj, by, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 384, in __init__
    grouper, exclusions, obj = _get_grouper(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/groupby/grouper.py", line 621, in _get_grouper
    raise KeyError(gpr)
KeyError: 'side-'

Comment: Based on the error, you don't have a `side-` column in your dataframe